# flask application starts correctly but shows an error once logged-in

Tags: flask

I am using the dockerized version of this python app.

https://github.com/tunl/cast-sh/blob/dev/cast/app.py

The home-page loads correctly. But after typing the default password "admin", I get an error.

```
[2021-04-30 15:07:23,451] ERROR in app: Exception on /cast [GET]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2292, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1815, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1718, in handle_user_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/_compat.py", line 35, in reraise
    raise value
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1813, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1799, in dispatch_request
    return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
TypeError: wrapper() missing 1 required positional argument: 'fn'
```

Not sure if this error is related to docker or flask.

```
Internal Server Error

The server encountered an internal error and was unable to complete your request. Either the server is overloaded or there is an error in the application.
```

Comment: can you add your Dockerfile content to understand more your issue ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that within the file ["routes.py", line 41](https://github.com/tunl/cast-sh/blob/d98cf545bfad49d17f5bbe636efa25465f306d97/cast/routes.py#L41) the brackets behind the decorator are missing.
It should read as follows because the decorator allows optional parameters and otherwise the function will not be wrapped correctly.

```
@http.route("/cast")
@jwt_required()
def index():
    # ...
```